# $H = \{ \frac{7}{6}n + \frac{5}{8}m \mid n, m \in \Bbb{Z} \}$ is a subgroup of $(\Bbb{Q}, +)$. Prove that $H$ is cyclic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

$H = \{  \frac{7}{6}n +  \frac{5}{8}m \mid n, m \in \Bbb{Z} \}$ is a subgroup of $(\Bbb{Q}, +)$. Prove that $H$ is cyclic

So from what I see, I need to find that an element from $H$ where $<h^k>$ = $H$. This means that I can use    $(\frac{7}{6}n + \frac{5}{8}m)^k$... Can I use the GCD for this?

so I added and got $<\frac{28n + 15m}{24}>$ and since LCM(28,15) = 1 then the linear combination can produce all the integers in Z? Therefore $\frac{1}{24}$ is a generator???

Comment: Note that in the abelian group $h^k$ really means that you add $h$ $k$ times, so $kh$! Moreover, you want to show that there exists some $h \in H$ such that $\langle h \rangle = H$, not $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: true, I edited that. I still don't get what abelian does in this. Besides, I cant use that since I have not discussed it.

Comment: hint:  can you find the least positive element in $H$?  That's certainly a likely candidate for a generator.

Comment: Abelian means the operation is commutative :)

Comment: `lcm(6,8)=24`. Try to write $\frac{1}{24}$ as $\frac{7}{6}n +  \frac{5}{8}m$

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ didn't know that $12$ was a multiple of $8$... ;)

Comment: @Student typo. edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note how:
$$\frac76n+\frac58m=\frac 1{24}(28n+15m)$$
And since $\gcd(28,15)=1$, we can find $n,m\in\mathbb{Z}$ with:
$$28n+15m=1$$
Hence $\frac1{24}\in H$. Therefore:
$$\langle\frac1{24}\rangle\subseteq H$$
But:
$$H=\{\frac76n+\frac58m|n,m\in\mathbb{Z}\}=\{\frac1{24}(28n+16m)|n,m\in\Bbb{Z}\}\subseteq\{\frac{n}{24}|n\in\Bbb{Z}\}=\langle\frac1{24}\rangle$$
We conclude that $H=\langle\frac1{24}\rangle$, so $H$ is cyclic.